# Molecule analog similar and commercially available

Tags: organic-chemistry

I wanted to carry out some experiments on the following molecule:

[image]

Unfortunately this molecule (santalene; either isomer will do) seems neither commercially available nor easily synthesizable.

Hence I am looking for analogs that I can start out with. Any idea which commercially available molecules might be similar to this molecule?

I did fine one analog (curcumene) but even that does not seem to be available with Sigma or any of the usual sources for even fairly esoteric molecules.

[image]

Any thoughts / tips? Alternatively, a synthesis for my target molecule might also help, in case I am missing any obvious routes.

PS. Any recommendations for tools / sites that will do a good search for analog molecules?

Comment: There's an old Corey paper on the synthesis of santalene [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00872a028)

Comment: Santalene is the primary constituent of sandalwood oil, which is commercially available.  You could isolate pure material by fractional distillation of the oil. http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/w300500?lang=en&region=US

Comment: @CurtF. Thanks. But to the best of my knowledge it is the Santalols which are the major constituents of the oil. Santalenes are 1-2% max. Separating enough from the oil seems difficult. But I could try that.

Comment: Good point @curious_cat.  You are right.  This info might be helpful: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22900258

Comment: Additionally, I found very old references in the literature that dehydration of $\alpha$-santolol leads (unfortunately) to "$\alpha$-iso-santalene" and similarly for the $\beta$ isomer.  I'm not 100% sure what the structure of  "iso-santalene" is but presumably it is not what you are interested in?

Comment: @CurtF. Any thoughts on what to use as the dehydrating agent?